# Stop all fillable items trying to save to database laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form with some items `firstname`, `surname`, `checkbox`

In my model I have

`$fillable = [firstname, surname, checkbox]`

`$appends = [checkbox]`

In my database only contains `firstname` and `surname`

The purpose of the checkbox is to signal something post saving in an observer.

I want to use mass assignment to set all these items.

However when it comes to saving my model it tries to save `checkbox` in the database.

How to get over this?

I dont want to singularly assign it with `$model->checkbox = Input::get('checkbox')` as I will eventually have lots of different items.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to do a dynamic properties for the model,
You can do it by:

- Create another table for `metadata` with columns: `key`, `value` and `model_id` for relation.
- Create `Metadata` model with `$fillable = ['key', 'value']`.
- Add `hasMany` relation in the default model with `Metadata` model.
- Create an array with the keys of extra properties

  ```
  $metadata = ['checkbox', 'foo', 'bar'];
  ```
- Do a loop on the array and save the value

  ```
  foreach($metadata as $key) {
      $model->metadata()->create([
          'key'   => $key,
          'value' => Request::get($key)
      ]);
  }
  ```